# Getting text of HTML elements to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, algorithm

I have the following html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <body>

        <div>
            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="1">
            <p id="2">Paragraph First
                <ol id="3">
                    <li id="4">alice
                        <ul id="31">
                            <li id="41">bob</li>
                            <li id="51">foo</li>
                            <li id="61">grow</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="5">coding</li>
                    <li id="6">fun</li>
            </ol>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p>Paragraph Second</p>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

I want to get the text of all the elements to an array(pre order transverse preffered).
So for the following example array consists of,

```
[My First Heading, first paragraph, Paragraph First, alice, bob, foo, grow, coding, fun]
```

I can use jQuery if it needsHow. can I achieve this ?

My own non-working attempt

```
var root = document.documentElement; 
recursivePreorder(root); // Recusively find and handle all text nodes 
function recursivePreorder(node) {   
  // If node is a text node   
  if (node.type == 3) {
    //add to the array   
  }   // else recurse for each child node   
  else {     
    for(var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++)       
      recursivePreorder(node.childNodes[i]);   
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

when my tag is `<li id="41">bob<a href="url">link text</a>alice</li>` it gives me as `[bob, link text, alice]` . But I want the output as `[bob<a href="url">link text</a>alice]` means links are working correctly. This is my current solution,

```
var arr=$('body').find('*').contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3&&this.textContent.trim()!=""; });
```

how to solve this problem ?

Comment: have you tried something yourself???

Comment: Shortest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7824394/295783

Comment: @Kartikeya Yeah. Following is my poor solution.
`var root = document.documentElement;
recursivePreorder(root);
// Recusively find and handle all text nodes
function recursivePreorder(node) {
  // If node is a text node
  if (node.type == 3) {
    //add to the array
  }
  // else recurse for each child node
  else {
    for(var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++)
      recursivePreorder(node.childNodes[i]);
  }
}
`
but it does not work :)

Comment: This may be useful to loop through the all body elements, and push into an array variable ,                                   $(function() {
    $('body').find('*').each(function() {
               
    });
});

Comment: @mplungjan That works great. But when I ran it in chrome console it gives me some elements named "#text" too. How to avoid it ?

Comment: They are the CRs. `$('body').find('*').contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.indexOf('\n')!=0; });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = $("#container *").contents().map(function() {
        if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim() != "") {
            return this.textContent.trim();
        }
    });

    console.log(arr);
});
```

`nodeType` will be 3 for text contents

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/60xL3zfu/5/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry I does not give me the array. When I log arr.length it outputs 0. Could you please help me to solve it ?

Comment: Great. Links seems separate the text content in both sides. how to avoid it ?

Comment: Great. Links seems separate the text content in both sides. how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = [];
$(document).find('li,p,h1').each(function(e){
    arr.push(($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text()).trim());
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/udjm1veu/1/)

Comment: Great. Links seems separate the text content in both sides. how to avoid it ?